# To evaluate $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\cos x}{x+2} dx $ and $\int_0^4{\frac{\sin x \cos x}{(x+1)^2}} dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to evaluate the following integrals?

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\cos x}{x+2} dx $$

$$\int_0^4{\frac{\sin x \cos x}{(x+1)^2}} dx$$

Comment: All of these involve sine ond cosine integrals.

Comment: Do you need an approximate value ? If not, you will stop with $Ci$'s and $Si$'s as shown by Lucian. If you want a method for approximating, let me know. I have to go now but I shall be back within 12 hours.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, approximating might help.

Answer (score 2):

> *How to evaluate the following integrals?*

By writing $\cos(x)$ as $\cos\Big((x+2)-2\Big)$, then applying the formula for $\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b$ $-\sin a\sin b$, and then employing the definition of the [trigonometric integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral) $\text{Ci}(x)$. Similarly for the second one, with the added mention that $\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$, and the [special function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral) used here will be $\text{Si}(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Using what Lucian answered $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\cos x}{x+2} dx=\left(\text{Ci}\left(2+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-\text{Ci}(2)\right) \cos
   (2)+\left(\text{Si}\left(2+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-\text{Si}(2)\right) \sin (2)$$ 
$$\int_0^4{\frac{\sin x \cos x}{(x+1)^2}} dx=\Big(\text{Ci}(10)-\text{Ci}(2)\Big) \cos (2)-\frac{1}{5} \sin (2) \Big(5 \text{Si}(2)-5
   \text{Si}(10)+\cos (2)+\cos (6)\Big)$$ The numerical values are respectively $0.3971615867$ and $0.1441361714$.